# Add text/date/time to webform with Python

Tags: python, webforms

I´m trying to fill a webform with python (see attached code).
There are four fields...two text fields which I managed to fill with 
"Start-Station" & "End-Station", a field for a date and one for a time.
Unfortunatelly, fields 3&4 do not fill up with my input-data. 
I guess they are not recognized correctly....
Does anybody know what I have to change so I can add data there?

Thanks for your help.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('...path-to...\chromedriver.exe')  
driver.get('https://www.bahn.de/p/view/index.shtml')  
Checkdata = ['Start-Station', 'End-Station',
                'Do, 12.03.20', '05:30']  
for Check in Checkdata:  
    driver.find_element_by_id("js-auskunft-autocomplete-from").send_keys(Checkdata[0])
    driver.find_element_by_id("js-auskunft-autocomplete-to").send_keys(Checkdata[1]) 
    driver.find_element_by_id("dp1583859161773").send_keys(Checkdata[2])    
    driver.find_element_by_id("js-auskunft-timeinput").send_keys(Checkdata[3])
```

Comment: As pointed out by @roarkz. You don't need to loop. You are directly addressing each element by specifying its index. For e.g. `Checkdata[2]` refers to the 3rd element in the `Checkdata` list

Comment: As an aside, variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working version.

At date and time you have to clear the input. On time if you clear the input it will auto complete, so you gonna use 5 times backspace and there you go.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.bahn.de/p/view/index.shtml')
Checkdata = ['Start-Station', 'End-Station',
                'Do, 12.03.20', '05:30']

driver.find_element_by_id("js-auskunft-autocomplete-from").send_keys(Checkdata[0])
driver.find_element_by_id("js-auskunft-autocomplete-to").send_keys(Checkdata[1])
driver.find_element_by_name("date").clear()
driver.find_element_by_name("date").send_keys(Checkdata[2])
for x in range(5):
    driver.find_element_by_name("time").send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE)
driver.find_element_by_name("time").send_keys(Checkdata[3])
```

Comment: Hi and thanks to all for your fast feedback. I will try your proposals and post the solution that works for me. Regards :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use `find_element_by_name`:

```
    driver.find_element_by_id("js-auskunft-autocomplete-from").send_keys(Checkdata[0])
    driver.find_element_by_id("js-auskunft-autocomplete-to").send_keys(Checkdata[1]) 
    driver.find_element_by_name("date").send_keys(Checkdata[2])    
    driver.find_element_by_name("time").send_keys(Checkdata[3])
```

Comment: Is the for loop needed here? `Check` is never used and it is only using data from the list.

Comment: It's not needed as far as I understand.

Answer (score 0):

enclosed my working solution containing some of your proposals:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome('path\to\.exe')
driver.get('https://www.bahn.de/p/view/index.shtml')

checkzeiten = ['start station', 'end statino','05:30']
#                , ['2', 'München Hbf', 'Hochzoll Bahnhof, Augsburg (Bayern)',
#               'Mi, 11.03.20', '16:00']]
#for Check in CheckZeiten:
driver.find_element_by_id("js-auskunft-autocomplete-from").send_keys(checkzeiten[0])
driver.find_element_by_id("js-auskunft-autocomplete-to").send_keys(checkzeiten[1]) 

#Date field already contains todays date...that´s OK

for x in range(5):  #delete old time from field & add new one
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/form/fieldset[1]/div[2]/div[2]/input').send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/form/fieldset[1]/div[2]/div[2]/input').send_keys(checkzeiten[2])

#click SUBMIT button
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/form/fieldset[5]/div/input[1]').click()
```